# How to deinit StateObject if I use its @Published vars in View on iOS 15

Tags: swiftui, combine

The StateObject doesn't deinit, if I use it's @Published var in an .alert() on iOS 15. It works fine on iOS 16. Take a look at the minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
struct MainUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Go to Child View", destination: ChildView())
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = ChildViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        
        //HERE. I have to use $vm.showingAlert from the StateObject:
        .alert("Alert Title", isPresented: $vm.showingAlert, actions: {
            Button("OK") { }
        }, message: {
            Text("Alert Message")
        })
    }
}

@MainActor final class ChildViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showingAlert = false
    
    init() {
        print("INIT")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("DE-INIT")
    }
}
```

If you go to ChildView and return back to Main View - you won't see "DE-INIT" printed in the console on iOS 15.

I've investigated the Memory Graph:
[image: Memory Graph]
and
[image: Detailed]
So the View is holding the `showingAlert` Publisher and thus the whole StateObject doesn't deinit. How can I make it deinit?

Comment: Why do you want it to `deinit`?  The child view is still using it as it has to listen in case `showingAlert` changes.  This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @ScottThompson try going to the ChildView and back. When you leave the Child screen - its StateObject should deinit. I've edited the main question for clarity.

Comment: Actually, your assumption that the child's view's `StateObject` should deinit is faulty. When you put a view into a `NavigationLink`, SwiftUI will preemptively create those views and will keep them around until they cannot be used (parent went out o the hierarchy), or memory is needed. So, what you are seeing is expected.

Comment: @Yrb interesting! I was just worried about creating memory leaks. Also, it happens on iOS 15 only. Why do they de-init right away on iOS 16?

Comment: That is an Apple question. Remember, though, they did change the navigation structures in iOS 16 to make things more performant and stable.

Answer (score 0):

It keeps it because you might rotate the device and it changes to a Split View and it will be shown in the detail pane.